# Application Package not finding config files

Tags: codeigniter

I’ve got two applications running in my CI deployment. I’m using a separate folder to hold shared resources between the two apps.

Then in autoload.php i have:

```
$autoload['packages'] = array(SHARED_RESOURCES_PATH);
```

I’m finding models and helpers load fine from the shared directory, however i’ve added a config folder with database.php and this doesn’t get loaded.

Anyone know why this would be?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the new *config* directory you created does not have the same permissions or ownership as your other shared directories; compare permissions/ownership & insure *config* matches the others (*this is usually the culprit when all else is functioning properly*).